# Turning off debugger in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

This may sound like a heresy :), but I mostly program in fortran (intel 10) and have actually no need for Visual Studio Debugger. Or at least, never have gotten used to it.

So to put it shortly, where does one turn it off ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: Why would you need to turn it off? Just don't use it!

Comment: Are you launching the debugger and need to know how to launch your app w/o the debugger or are you actually talking about uninstalling the debugger?

Comment: Visual Studio 2080? Are you from the future? O_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Ctrl+F5` to start running without the debugger. This can also be accessed from the Debug menu, as "Start without debugging".

You can also change the project configuration from Debug to Release, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx).

Comment: It had to be right below the one I click several times a day ... it just had to :)

Comment: You can also add this command to Debug menu by the following steps:

Tools->Customize->Commands tab->Click Rearrange Commands button->Select Debug from Menu Bar dropdownlist->and then Click Add button->Select Debug from Categories and then Select Start without debugging from Commands->OK.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean Visual Studio 2008 (sorry, stupid remark).

Do you want to get rid of the "Do you want to start the debugger" question if your application crashes?
In that case, you may want to look at the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug".  You will find there entries to configure this popup (appear or not, which application to start at crash, ...).

Answer (score 1):

`[Debug - Start without Debugging] or Ctrl F5`.
Or launch your app outside Visual Studio.